# LIMPIAR CAMPOS DE UN MODAL

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, modal, webforms

Tengo un modal en `bootstrap`, pero cuando lo cierro y luego lo vuelvo a abrir, me aparecen los datos anteriores en todos los campos, es decir, no se limpian, he utilizado diversas soluciones con `jQuery`, pero ninguna me resulta por completo.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="container modal-dialog" id="modalTamano" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                          <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold" class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Nuevo Producto</h4>
                                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                  </button>
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-body">
                               <div class="modal-body1">
                                     <div class="row">
                                           <div class="col-xs-4">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label>Codigo</label>
                                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCodigo" CssClass="form-control" BackColor="LightGreen"></asp:TextBox>
                                                 </div>
                                           </div>
                                          <div class="col-xs-4">
                                                   <label>Categoria</label>
                                                   <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlCategoria" CssClass="form-control" BackColor="LightGreen">
                                                      <asp:ListItem>General</asp:ListItem>
                                                      <asp:ListItem>Consumo Saludable</asp:ListItem>
                                                  </asp:DropDownList>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="col-xs-4">
                                                    <label>Peso</label>
                                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPeso" CssClass="form-control solo-numero" BackColor="LightGreen"></asp:TextBox>
                                          </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                         <div class="col-xs-12">
                                                  <label>Descripcion</label>
                                                  <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDescricion" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="2" CssClass="form-control" BackColor="LightGreen"></asp:TextBox>
                                         </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <br />
                                    <div class="row">
                                         <div class="box-body table-responsive">
                                              <table id="tblRegistroProducto" class="table table-bordered table-hover text-center">
                                                 <thead>
                                                     <tr>
                                                         <th style="width: 9%">Pais</th>
                                                         <th style="width: 21%">Nombre</th>
                                                         <th style="width: 9%">Puntos</th>
                                                         <th style="width: 11%">P. Publico</th>
                                                         <th style="width: 11%">P. Socio</th>
                                                         <th>Imagen</th>
                                                         <th>Descuento</th>
                                                         <th>Estado</th>
                                                     </tr>
                                                 </thead>
                                                    <tbody id="tbl_body_table2">
                                                       <tr>
                                                           <th>Perú</th>
                                                           <th>
                                                               <input id="txtNombreProdPeru" style="width: 100%; background-color: lightgreen" placeholder="Nombre" class="form-control" /></th>
                                                           <th>
                                                               <input id="txtPuntosProdPeru" style="width: 100%; background-color: lightgreen" placeholder="Puntos" class="form-control solo-numero" /></th>
                                                           <th>
                                                               <input id="txtPrecioProdPeru" style="width: 100%; background-color: lightgreen" placeholder="Precio" class="form-control solo-numero" /></th>
                                                           <th>
                                                               <input id="txtPrecioSocioPeru" style="width: 100%; background-color: lightgreen" placeholder="Precio" class="form-control solo-numero" /></th>
                                                           <th>
                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                    <label style="width: 130px" class="file-upload btn btn-success">
                                                                    Ingrese la imagen ...
                                                                    <input id="imgPeru" type="file" />
                                                                    </label>

                                                                 </div>
                                                             </th>
                                                             <th>

                                                                 <div class="checkbox checkbox-success">
                                                                    <input id="checkDescPeru" name="checkDescPeru" type="checkbox">
                                                                    <label for="checkDescPeru" style="color: lightgreen; font-size: small">
                                                                    Desc. Adicional
                                                                    </label>
                                                                 </div>
                                                              </th>
                                                              <th>
                                                                 <div class="checkbox" id="switchTamano">
                                                                 <input id="tooglePeru" type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">
                                                                 </div>
                                                               </th>        
                                                       </tr>
                                                   </tbody>
                                              </table>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                                    <button id="btnId" type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Aceptar</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

He utilizado este código, pero al reiniciar los valores me bloquea las opciones del `checkbox`, el `toogle` y la carga de imagenes.

```
var template = null

$('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    if (template == null) {
        template = $(this).html()
    } else {
        $(this).html(template)
    }
    // other initialization here, if you want to

       $('.file-upload').file_upload();
       $('.solo-numero').numeric();
})
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad. Adicional coloca el html del modal (solo el modal y su contenido).

Comment: Cuando dices todo el modal, eso incluye los textbox de asp y los input de la tabla tblRegistroProducto

Comment: Correcto, quiere que se limpie todo el modal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para limpiar los valores de entrada del modal puedes hacer de la siguiente forma:

```
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    $("#exampleModal input").val("");
    $("#exampleModal textarea").val("");
    $("#exampleModal select").val("");
    $("#exampleModal input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', false).change();
});
```

Tambien puedes probar de esta forma:

```
$("#exampleModal").find("input,textarea,select").val("");
$("#exampleModal input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', false).change();
```

En los dos casos siempre se limpia el valor con `val()` y para los input tipo checkbox se le modifica el atributo checked a falso.

*Nota: los ejemplo que te coloco no han sido probado para los controles de asp, solo es una guia de como deberias hacerlo, en cuanto para los demas campos de entrada si deberia de funcionar perfectamente.*

Comment: Ya lo intente, me funciona bien los input y el dropdown, pero el check se mantiene seleccionado, de igual manera el toogle y el label de la imagen seleccionada.

Comment: A los checkbox al final hasle un change. Te actualizo la respuesta. Te quedo debiendo el fileinput.

Comment: En cuanto a la label que queda en el fileinput, podrias subir una imagen?

Comment: Esa es la imagen, el change me sirvió para cambiar el toogle, pero el checkbox se mantiene seleccionado: [Google](https://ibb.co/N7bBXr5)  <-- esa es la imagen.

Comment: al checkbox intenta con: `$("#checkDescPeru").removeAttr('checked')`

Comment: Pergunta: tienes algun evento asociado al fileinput?

Comment: Sigue apareciendo marcado el checkbox; en el fileinput lo realizo mediante $('.file-upload').file_upload();

Comment: El checkbox es total mente independiente del checkbox-toogle o entan relacionados entre si.

Comment: El checkbox es independiente

Answer (score 1):

Puedes limpiar el valor del template o de tus valores utilizando la instrucción `val` , es decir:

`$('.template').val('');`

`$('.file-upload').val('');`

`$('.solo-numero').val('')`

Comment: Acabo de agregar el modal a mi pregunta; realizando los ejemplos que me mencionas, no me limpia ningun valor al cerrar el modal.

Comment: Cuando cierres el modal llama a la siguiente instrucción `$(".modal-body input").val('')`  o puedes limpiar cada campo: 


`$('#txtCodigo').val('');`

`$('#txtDescricion').val('');`

`$('#ddlCategoria').val('');`